# Z3 Problems with push/pop with Python-API

Tags: z3, z3py

I am using Z3 with the Python-API.
I am setting up a quite big set of linear arithmetic constraints.

However, `push`/`pop` is causing the `check()` to run infinite.

If I dont't use any `push`/`pop`, everthing works fine. But when I just insert a

```
s.push()

s.pop()
```

somewhere before the `s.check()`, then the `s.check()` runs endless.
Only using the `push` without `pop` works fine.

Is there any known Issue and workaround about this? 
I am using Z3 [version 4.3.1 - 64 bit] on MacOS 10.7.5.

Thanks a lot & regards,
  Klaus

Comment: Can you provide a link to a rise4fun-example that shows the described behaviour?

Comment: Dear Malte, you can find an example here:
http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/UATh

with the given values for NUM_A and NUM_B, it solves the problem when I do not use any push() & Pop(), but it comes a timeout when I add the push() in line 23. 
This effect is much higher with NUM_B = 10 instead of NUM_B = 3. Then Z3py solves the problem in appropriate time, but it needs much longer resp. endless when adding the push().

I don't understand why the runtime differs so much just because the push() & pop()!?

Thanks, 
 Klaus

PS. is it possible to define the timeout also in python script?

Answer (score 1):

Z3 is a collection of solvers. However, only one of them is incremental.
The non-incremental solvers are much more efficient for your problem.
When you use `s.push()`, Z3 "guesses" you want to solve problems incrementally, and switches to the incremental (general purpose) solver.

If we add the following command in the beginning of the file, Z3 will display several  messages. Note that the messages are completely different when we use `s.push()`.

```
    set_option(verbose=10)
```

We can force Z3 to use a particular solver. For example, if we replace

```
  s = Solver()
```

with

```
  s = Tactic('qflia').solver()
```

Then, Z3 will use the efficient solver even when `s.push()` is used. 
However, it will start every `check()` command from scratch. I don't think this is a problem in your problem because the different in performance between the non-incremental and incremental is very big.

Comment: Dear Leonardo, thanks! The qflia-tactic works fine for me. However, I had an 's.reset()' in my code, this forces a 'Segmentation fault: 11' resp. an 'c.py(39): error: exception: access violation reading 0x00000008'. I removed the 's.reset()' and now it works. Is reset() not allowed for qflia or is this a bug?

Comment: One more question ;) Is there any rise4fun example where I can see how to setup timeouts when calling s.check() from python API? thanks

Comment: The `Segfault` has been fixed in the `unstable` (work-in-progress) branch. The fix is also available in the nightly builds (http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/leonardo/blog/2013/02/15/precompiled.html).